# Need assistance scraping HTML able from basketball-reference

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to webscraping with python/BeautifulSoup/urllib.request, and have been trying to figure out how to scrape this table for the longest time. I found some other code online and tried it out and have been trying to understand how they work and modifying them, but they always filter out the first column, which I need.

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy 

# NBA season we will be analyzing
month = "january"
# URL page we will scrape (see image above)
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_games-{}.html".format(month)
# this is the HTML for given URL
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# use findALL() to get the column headers
soup.findAll()
# use getText()to extract the text we need into a list
headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]
# exclude the first column as we will not need the ranking order from Basketball Reference for the analysis
headers=headers[1:]

# avoid the first header row
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]

player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]

for i in range(len(rows))]
df = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
```

[This is what the HTML table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7to6.png)

Can someone show me how to scrape this website for the table? I can't figure this out for the life of me
https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_games-january.html

Comment: It's OK if you can't get it to work, but please share the code of what you expected to work and explain why you think it's not working, or what part you're having problems with. You say you already have some Python code, so that's a good starting point.

Comment: I think I got it. should be pasted at the top. So the part I'm having trouble with is that it doesn't include the first column. I know the first column is a different type of tag than the rest, but I don't know how to get it in my dataframe

Comment: Ok we can see the code. (Please fix the indenting and formatting in future, I did it for this time).

Comment: hey thank you so much! I am going to study the code to figure out where I went wrong and what you did. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Ah only now see your actual problem, the first column has `<th>` instead of `<td>` elements - will adjust.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_games-january.html"


# Get a list of tables on the page
df_list = pd.read_html(url)


# Print info.
print(f"Number of tables found: {len(df_list)}") # Out: Number of tables found: 1


# Select first dataframe object and go to town.
df = df_list[0]


print(f"Found {df.shape[0]} rows and {df.shape[1]} columns.") # Found 238 rows and 10 columns.

# You can also drop some of those fields, like the ones for Box Score and Notes, which don't contain too much relevant info:

df.drop(["Unnamed: 6", "Unnamed: 7", "Notes"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output -

```
               Date Start (ET)    Visitor/Neutral    PTS       Home/Neutral  PTS.1  Attend.
0  Fri, Jan 1, 2021      7:00p  Memphis Grizzlies  108.0  Charlotte Hornets   93.0      0.0
1  Fri, Jan 1, 2021      7:00p         Miami Heat   83.0   Dallas Mavericks   93.0      0.0
2  Fri, Jan 1, 2021      7:00p     Boston Celtics   93.0    Detroit Pistons   96.0      0.0
3  Fri, Jan 1, 2021      7:30p      Atlanta Hawks  114.0      Brooklyn Nets   96.0      0.0
4  Fri, Jan 1, 2021      8:00p      Chicago Bulls   96.0    Milwaukee Bucks  126.0      0.0
```

---

**EDIT**: I see there's some naysayers out here, so let's go old school:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(url) as resp:
    data = resp.read().decode("utf-8")


def clean_data(d):
    """Replace newline, tab, and whitespace with single space."""
    return re.sub("\s{2}", " ", re.sub(r"(\t|\n|\s)+", "  ", d.strip()))


# Capture key segments by element tag and string indexing.
tbl_head = data[data.index("<thead"):data.index("</thead>")]
tbl_body = data[data.index("<tbody"):data.index("</tbody>")]


# Clean our head and body data.
tbl_head = clean_data(tbl_head)
tbl_body = clean_data(tbl_body)


# Simple match to get fields from the table.
# \S gets everything besides whitespace.
th_pat = r">(\S+)<"
p = re.compile(th_pat)
fields = p.findall(tbl_head)


Output of fields:

['Date',
 'Visitor/Neutral',
 'PTS',
 'Home/Neutral',
 'PTS',
 '&nbsp;',
 '&nbsp;',
 'Attend.',
 'Notes']


# Creative pattern to capture nested elements.
body_pat = r"""
    <t(?:h|d) .+?>
    (?:<a.+?>)?
    (.*?)
    (?:</a>)?
    </t\w>
    """
p = re.compile(body_pat, flags = re.X) # Use re.X if doing multiline pattern.


# Further cleaning of body data to remove whitespace.
# (Not super necessary.)
body_data = re.sub(r'("|<t\w) >', r'\1>', tbl_body)
body_data = re.sub(r'>\s+<', '><', body_data)

# Replace <tr> tags with newline character.
body_data = re.sub(r'(<tr>|</tr><tr>)', '\n', body_data)

# Iterate each line, capture our pattern output and add it as a sublist to res.
res = []
for line in body_data.split("\n"):
    tmp = p.findall(line)
    if len(tmp) > 0:
        res.append(tmp)


# First five lines of results
print("\n".join([f"{i}" for i in res[:5]]))
```

Output -

```
['Fri, Jan 1, 2021', '7:00p', 'Memphis Grizzlies', '108', 'Charlotte Hornets', '93', 'Box Score', '', '0', '']
['Fri, Jan 1, 2021', '7:00p', 'Miami Heat', '83', 'Dallas Mavericks', '93', 'Box Score', '', '0', '']
['Fri, Jan 1, 2021', '7:00p', 'Boston Celtics', '93', 'Detroit Pistons', '96', 'Box Score', '', '0', '']
['Fri, Jan 1, 2021', '7:30p', 'Atlanta Hawks', '114', 'Brooklyn Nets', '96', 'Box Score', '', '0', '']
['Fri, Jan 1, 2021', '8:00p', 'Chicago Bulls', '96', 'Milwaukee Bucks', '126', 'Box Score', '', '0', '']
```

Comment: Ok but pandas only works on a subset ot HTML (and no JS), can't handle nested/malformed tags etc. Better to diagnose why the OP's BeautifulSoup code wasn't working right.

Comment: With webscraping, whatever works is a good solution, you're always dependent on the page not changing anyway - I think the pandas solution is probably going to be more robust that anything more specific a coder would come up with. And it does work, so there's no reason not to. However, getting it to work with bs isn't hard either, as shown.

Comment: Also, @smci, bs won't work with JavaScript either, unless you pull in stuff like a headless browser (selenium, etc.), which is well beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Grismar: that's beside the point. I've done scraping with pandas and with BS. pandas is brittle and not scaleable unless the HTML is super-clean, which is not realistic. BS is more cantankerous but much more forgiving of real-world. "Drop BS and use pandas" is in general awful bad advice. The OP asked why their BS code wasn't working, not "How should I scrape this?"

Comment: As Mark shows, pandas deals OK with this site - as I showed below, the BS code simply didn't work because it ignored the header. The site is actually very clean. You're right, it won't work for sites driven by JS, or with bad html, but that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

@MarkMoretto has it right, just let `pandas` do the work. If you want to get bs working though, it's not hard either.

Part of what you're doing can be briefer, but yours works as well:

```
# specific to this page, you want the first table ([0]) and skip the first header ([1:])
headers = [elem.text for elem in soup.findAll('thead')[0].findAll('th')][1:]
```

And the data:

```
# now the data matches the headers, again, getting the data from the first table ([0])
data = [[elem.text for elem in row.findAll('td')] for row in soup.findAll('tbody')[0].findAll('tr')]
# getting the dates from the headers on the rows
index = [datetime.strptime(elem.text, '%a, %b %d, %Y').date() for elem in soup.findAll('tbody')[0].findAll('th')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers, index=index)
```

Now, you'll need to import `datetime` of course, the result:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

month = "january"
url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_games-{}.html".format(month)
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

headers = [elem.text for elem in soup.findAll('thead')[0].findAll('th')][1:]

data = [[elem.text for elem in row.findAll('td')] for row in soup.findAll('tbody')[0].findAll('tr')]
index = [datetime.strptime(elem.text, '%a, %b %d, %Y').date() for elem in soup.findAll('tbody')[0].findAll('th')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers, index=index)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           Start (ET)       Visitor/Neutral  PTS            Home/Neutral  PTS               Attend. Notes
2021-01-01      7:00p     Memphis Grizzlies  108       Charlotte Hornets   93  Box Score          0
2021-01-01      7:00p            Miami Heat   83        Dallas Mavericks   93  Box Score          0
2021-01-01      7:00p        Boston Celtics   93         Detroit Pistons   96  Box Score          0
2021-01-01      7:30p         Atlanta Hawks  114           Brooklyn Nets   96  Box Score          0
2021-01-01      8:00p         Chicago Bulls   96         Milwaukee Bucks  126  Box Score          0
...               ...                   ...  ...                     ...  ...        ... ..     ...   ...
2021-01-31      5:00p    Philadelphia 76ers               Indiana Pacers
2021-01-31      5:00p  Los Angeles Clippers              New York Knicks
2021-01-31      6:00p         Orlando Magic              Toronto Raptors
2021-01-31      7:00p         Brooklyn Nets           Washington Wizards
2021-01-31      7:30p   Cleveland Cavaliers       Minnesota Timberwolves

[238 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. the first column uses a '' tag rather than '', all the other columns use ''. The code you used is only looking for '' (`for td in rows[i].findAll('td')...`) hence it excludes the first (date) column.**
2. then remove the unneeded hack line `headers = headers[1:]` in the code you copied.

Here's the BeautifulSoup answer (BS is more forgiving of real-world HTML (nested, malformed tags) than pandas which is very brittle unless the HTML is super-clean, which is not realistic).

So your code is trying to parse each row of table. Let's just debug by looking at `rows[0]`; mentally ignore the HTML tags and just see that all your player stats are in fact correctly there:

```
>>> print(BeautifulSoup.prettify(rows[0]))

<tr>
 <th class="left" csk="202101010CHO" data-stat="date_game" scope="row">
  <a href="/boxscores/index.fcgi?month=1&amp;day=1&amp;year=2021">
   Fri, Jan 1, 2021
  </a>
 </th>
 <td class="right" data-stat="game_start_time">
  7:00p
 </td>
 <td class="left" csk="MEM.202101010CHO" data-stat="visitor_team_name">
  <a href="/teams/MEM/2021.html">
   Memphis Grizzlies
  </a>
 </td>
 <td class="right" data-stat="visitor_pts">
  108
 </td>
 <td class="left" csk="CHO.202101010CHO" data-stat="home_team_name">
  <a href="/teams/CHO/2021.html">
   Charlotte Hornets
  </a>
 </td>
 <td class="right" data-stat="home_pts">
  93
 </td>
 <td class="center" data-stat="box_score_text">
  <a href="/boxscores/202101010CHO.html">
   Box Score
  </a>
 </td>
 <td class="center iz" data-stat="overtimes">
 </td>
 <td class="right iz" data-stat="attendance">
  0
 </td>
 <td class="left iz" data-stat="game_remarks">
 </td>
</tr>
```

So, we need to rewrite:

```
player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
```

as:

```
player_stats = [[tc.getText() for tc in rows[0].findAll(['th','td'])]]
```

Note that `findAll()` will accept a list of tags `['th','td']`.

and I renamed the variable `tc` as in 'table cell', because it can be 'th' or 'td'.

Then this brings us to a second bug:

```
ValueError: 9 columns passed, passed data had 10 columns
>>> headers
['Start (ET)', 'Visitor/Neutral', 'PTS', 'Home/Neutral', 'PTS', '\xa0', '\xa0', 'Attend.', 'Notes']
```

`columns` 8 and 9 are blank, and one of them isn't being read.

This is because of the unneeded hack line `headers = headers[1:]` in the code you copied.

But a cleaner way to define `headers` is:

```
>>> [th.text for th in soup.findAll('thead')[0].findAll('th')]

['Date', 'Start (ET)', 'Visitor/Neutral', 'PTS', 'Home/Neutral', 'PTS', '\xa0', '\xa0', 'Attend.', 'Notes']
```